# Python is not working properly should I reinstall it?

Tags: python, macos, pip, download, package

I have python3.8 installed in my Mac but is not working properly: it's not finding pip (even though it is installed), and the IDE is not opening either. I think it's actually my fault, I delated a bunch of files and packages in my computer related to it, that I thought were not useful.
Would it be a good solution to install again python so that I get all the right packages too?
Other suggestion are more than welcome,
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you do a fresh installation of python again. Trying to fix the problem manually can be a hassle depending on what you deleted. Just reinstall python and I believe everything will be fixed. If not, get back to me :)

Comment: Ok thanks al lot, I was just worried that the what is left of the python that I already have could generate problems if I install the same version again

Comment: Theoretically speaking that's not supposed to happen since a new installation will scan for existing files and do what's required

Comment: wonderful, I din't know it, thanks! I'll let u know if it works